# Почему Vite не подгружает js?

Tags: php, laravel, vite

почему vite не подгружает js? Изначально в конце кода было так -

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/core.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

но так как я хочу использовать Vite в laravel - я переделал на -

```
@vite(['resources/js/core.min.js', 'resources/js/script.js'])
```

но увы, ничего не работает

Также вот конфиг vite -

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/core.min.js',
                'resources/js/script.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Vite использует `npm` "команды". Для работы в Laravel их заготовлено две:

1. `npm run dev` - для локальной разработки. После запуска команды, npm-процесс продолжает работать и по вебсокету обновляет страницу в браузере, если были внесены правки в определённые файлы;
2. `npm run build` - генерирует файлы, для рабочей версии.

Comment: Да, я это знаю, и использую npm run dev на данный момент